# Show image stream from webcam attached to rasberry pi on Android using http server

Tags: android, python, opencv, raspberry-pi, bottle

My team and I are working on a robotics project at university. We have a Rasberry Pi to which we attach a webcam and do image processing using OpenCV. The Rasberry Pi does some processing and communicates with an Arduino onboard and the Arduino then goes on to do something useful such as move the robot forward, turn etc.

The project also involves making an Android app which will (amongst other things) be used to control the robot and show a feed of the camera mounted on the robot (connected to Rasberry Pi). My question involves solving the problem of -- showing images from that webcam on my Android App.

For communication, I use bottlePy (https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/), a WSGI python framework. The relevant code for this (on Rasberry Pi) is:

```
from bottle import route, run, template
from bottle import static_file

@route('/static/<filename>')
def server_static(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='./') 

run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

This code simply returns an image when I open [http://*ip*:8080/static/image.jpg](http://_ip_:8080/static/image.jpg).

Now for getting and saving the image to disk, so that the server can pick it up, I have another script running on the Pi:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time 

while 1:
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    s, img = cam.read() # captures image
    cv2.imwrite("image.jpg",img,[int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY),50])
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

This script can either be run seperately or I can move this code into my server code, but moving it to the server code gace me issues that I'll explain in a bit with my android code.

The stream on android does not need to be very smooth. But here is what I do:

I create a runnable and use a handler to call the runnable every 100 ms:

```
runnable = object : Runnable {
        override fun run() {
            /* do what you need to do */
            try {
                val performBackgroundTask = DownloadImageTask(findViewById(R.id.imageView))
                // PerformBackgroundTask this class is the class that extends AsynchTask
                performBackgroundTask.execute("http://$id:8080/static/image.jpg")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
            /* and here comes the "trick" */
            handler.postDelayed(this, 100)
        }
    }
```

The code for my AsyncTask:

```
class DownloadImageTask(val bmImage: ImageView) : AsyncTask<String,Void,Bitmap>() {

val tag = "DownloadImageTask"

override fun doInBackground(vararg urls: String?): Bitmap? {

    val urldisplay = urls[0]
    var mIcon11: Bitmap? = null
    try {
        val `in` = java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream()
        if (`in` != null) {
            mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(`in`)
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e(tag, e.message)
        e.printStackTrace()
    }

    return mIcon11
}

override fun onPostExecute(result: Bitmap?) {
    if (result != null)
        bmImage.setImageBitmap(result)
}
}
```

So I simply change the source of my image view.

Now comes the problem, these things don't sync! I get partial images (image blacked from bottom-up to some hight). I believe this is because while the server is sending the image, the script rewrites the image. Basically, I've got a stream working, but like a fluctuation, the stream has bad images.

I thought that I'll only save an image before sending by adding the image saving code into server_static() function. But with that, the server takes time to respond and before it can send an image, another request is added to the queue. And then when I stop the stream in the Android app, by

```
handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)
```

the server still keeps on sending the images for sometime and any other requests are delayed.

I need a soultion for this or a totally another way to get this done. Help please? (Sorry for the long question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I figured out the best solution for me.

First, to get a consistent stream of Jpeg(s), I created a Mjpeg stream and made it accessible on the local network (HTTP server). Mjpeg(s) ensure a smooth flow of sequential images. It is much better than saving images to local storage and then sending them over an HTTP server.

One example code for Mjpeg server can be found here: https://gist.github.com/n3wtron/4624820, another is https://hardsoftlucid.wordpress.com/2013/04/11/mjpeg-server-for-webcam-in-python-with-opencv/ .

The python codes from either of the examples above can be run on the Rasberry Pi. I prefer the second as it allows multiple access to the stream.

Now for Android, I use https://github.com/niqdev/ipcam-view. This makes streaming a mjpeg stream on Android really easy. However, I have had some problems. It doesn't work with all types of cameras and occasionally makes my app crash. But I'm sure I can work around it (changing the camera helped). Furthermore, I require to Start and Stop the stream on click of a button. I haven't been able to do this yet. It starts but only stops when I exit that activity. There are other projects out there that make mjpg streaming easy for Android, if I find a better one, I'll update the answer. Until then, this is a good solution.

EDIT: Another simpler way to show mjpeg stream on Android:
I get best results when I use a WebView. To start a stream, use

```
webView.loadUrl("http://localhost:8080/cam.mjpeg")
```

And to fit the video well, in your onCreate funtion:

```
// All code in Kotlin, for Java, use functions instead of preperty access syntax
webView.settings.loadWithOverviewMode = true;
webView.settings.useWideViewPort = true;
```